# my tagged questions link give error

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-filters

when i click on "tagged questions" link, loaded page https://stackexchange.com/filters/popular

but if i click on "my filters" i see error:

```
 We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.

It's not you, it's us. This is our fault.

Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.

It's not strictly necessary, but if you'd like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, http://meta.stackoverflow.com.
```

I have this error during last 3 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now.

The bug was caused by your automatically imported favorite tags, one of which was `*` (from [your IT security account](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/666/rusalex?tab=prefs)).

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. Is this due to some tag in particular?

Have your tried to rebuild the tag list?

You can always clear cookies and cache from you browser to be sure you don't have a problem on your side. (Even if the site said it's his fault... who knows).

Comment: deleting cookies, doesn't help. And i cant even access to my tag lists. "My filters" link gives me that error.

Comment: Other browsers?